# How can you use JavaScript to send a video blob to a Django view using a Django form?

Tags: javascript, django, video, django-forms, blob

## In a nutshell

How can I use JavaScript to get a blob of video data to a Django view through a Django form?

## Background

I'm building a feature to record a webcam video. I've successfully figured this part out. I can use JavaScript to stream the user's camera and mic, record the stream, turning it into a blob, and then I'm able to turn the blob into a file. However, I don't want a file because I need users' videos to simply be sent to my backend, and I don't want users to interact with a video file (and I just learned that you can't programmatically assign `<input type='file'>` elements a file because of security reasons). *This is why I'm looking to just send the binary data.*

## What I've Tried (and what the result was)

- Like I said, I tried using a FileField in my Django form (but cuz inherent web security restrictions, no worky). Having users download and upload the file themselves does not work with project requirements.
- I've tried using a JSONField for my Django form and submitting the binary in JSON format. Perhaps this could still work, but I can't get the binary data into JSON format. With everything I've tried so far, value in my JSON that should have the blob ends up being either an empty string, `undefined`, or a string like this -> `"data:"`.

## Code

### JavaScript

```js
// This function is what MediaRecorder uses to give data to "recordedChunks"
const handleDataAvailable = function(event) {
  if (event.data.size > 0) {
    recordedChunks.push(event.data);
  } else {
    // …
  }
}
```

The problem lies in the next step (stop recording, make blob, and get blob to `input` element). I will show each variation of this function, explaining beforehand what the value of `base64data` ended up being:

#### `console.log(base64data);` = `undefined`

```js
const stopCapture = function() {
  mediaRecorder.stop();

  const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {type: "video/webm",});

  // Convert the Blob to base64 and then JSON format to submit with form
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function () {
    const base64data = reader.result.split(',')[1];
    console.log(base64data);
    const jsonData = JSON.stringify({ videoBlob: base64data });
    
    // Set the value of the input element to the base64-encoded blob
    jsonInput.value = jsonData;
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
}
```

#### `console.log(base64data);` = `data:`

Changed `const base64data = reader.result.split(',')[1];` to `const base64data = reader.result;`.

#### `console.log(base64data);` = an empty string

```js
//...after blob is created
// Convert the Blob to base64 and then JSON format to submit with form
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function () {
    const arrayBuffer = reader.result;

    // Convert array buffer to base64
    const base64data = arrayBufferToBase64(arrayBuffer);

    // Create a JSON-formatted string with the base64-encoded blob data
    const jsonData = JSON.stringify({ videoBlob: base64data });

    // Set the value of the hidden input to the JSON representation
    blobInput.value = jsonData;
  };
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
}
// Function to convert array buffer to base64
function arrayBufferToBase64(arrayBuffer) {
  const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
  const binaryString = uint8Array.reduce((acc, byte) => acc + String.fromCharCode(byte), '');
  return btoa(binaryString);
}
```

## Other Ideas

- Maybe it would be best to not use a Django form? If I did this, then I would submit the form data through JavaScript itself to a separate view in Django (using `formData()` and `fetch()`). However, I'd rather not do this because I like the built-in security that Django forms provide.
- Perhaps it's best to send the data to my Django backend (a separate view) *before* turning it into a blob somehow?

## Django form and view code

Including this just in case there are suggestions about my overall workflow since my end goal is to go from the user recording a video to my backend sending that video to a 3rd party storage service.

### forms.py

```py
from django import forms

class VidFileUploadForm(forms.Form):
    vidBlob = forms.JSONField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    descrip = forms.CharField(required=True)
```

### views.py

```py
class VidDemoTwoView(FormMixin, TemplateView, ProcessFormView):
    """View class for experimental video recording view"""
    template_name = 'evaluations/vid_demo2.html'
    form_class = VidFileUploadForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('view-vid-demo')
    
    def form_valid(self, form):

        vidBlob = form.cleaned_data['vidBlob']
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        description = form.cleaned_data['descrip']

        #logic to turn video blob into video file and then upload to 3rd party storage service

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the approach to work. My problem was the MediaRecorder wasn't finished doing its thing before I was attempting to create the blob. Here's my full script so you can see how I fixed it (creating the `recordingPromise` and making stopCapture an `async` function were key (so that I could `await` the recordingPromise before trying to create the blob)):

#### JavaScript

```
/* ------------------- 
-------- Capture -------
------------------- */
const vidDisplay = document.querySelector("#vidDisplay");
const startRecordBtn = document.querySelector("#startRecordBtn");
const stopRecordBtn = document.querySelector("#stopRecordBtn");
const sendBtn = document.querySelector("#sendBtn");
const blobInput = document.querySelector("#id_vidBlob");
const resultDisplay = document.querySelector("#result");

/* -------------------------
--------- Variables ---------- 
--------------------------- */
// gotta have the chunks
const recordedChunks = [];

// User media constraints
const constraints = {
  audio: true,
  video: {
    width: 640,
    height: 360
  }
};
// declare stream globally
let stream;
// declare mediaRecorder globally
let mediaRecorder;
// declare recordingPromise globally
let recordingPromise;
// Recorder options
const recorderOptions = {
  mimeType: "video/webm; codecs=vp9",
  audioBitsPerSecond: 8000,
  videoBitsPerSecond: 156250,
};

/* -------------------------
--------- Functions ---------- 
--------------------------- */

// Function for starting screen capture
const startCapture = async function() {
  try {
    stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
    vidDisplay.srcObject = stream;

    // create media recorder
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, recorderOptions);
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = handleDataAvailable;

    // start up recorder
    mediaRecorder.start();

    // Create a promise to resolve when the recording is stopped
    recordingPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
      mediaRecorder.onstop = resolve;
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

// Function for recorder
const handleDataAvailable = function(event) {
  console.log("data is available");
  if (event.data.size > 0) {
    recordedChunks.push(event.data);
  } else {
    // …
  }
}

// Function for stopping screen capture
const stopCapture = async function() {
  let tracks = vidDisplay.srcObject.getTracks();

  tracks.forEach((track) => track.stop());
  vidDisplay.srcObject = null;

  // stop ye recorder
  mediaRecorder.stop();

  await recordingPromise;

  const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {type: "video/webm",}); // create blob from recordedChunks

  // Convert the Blob to base64 and then JSON format to submit with form
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onloadend = function () {
    try {
      const base64data = reader.result.split(',')[1];;
      console.log(base64data);

      // Create a JSON-formatted string with the base64-encoded blob data
      const jsonData = JSON.stringify({ videoBlob: base64data });
      
      // Set the value of the hidden input to the base64-encoded blob
      blobInput.value = jsonData;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error during FileReader operation:', error);
    }
  };

  // read video data
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
}

/* -------------------------
--------- Event Listeners ---------- 
--------------------------- */

startRecordBtn.addEventListener("click", startCapture);
stopRecordBtn.addEventListener("click", stopCapture);
```

This made it so I could easily submit the blob in the JSONField that I created in my form, and it's proving pretty easy to work with that in the view so that I can upload the video file to a 3rd party storage service.